# Momentum conservation in Vlasov Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

The 3-dimensional Vlassov -Poisson equation I am studying at university is
$$ \partial_t f (t,x,v) + v\cdot \nabla_x f (t,x,v) - \nabla_x \phi (t,x) \cdot\nabla_v f (t,x,v) =0,$$
where $$\Delta \phi = 4\pi\gamma\, \rho(t,x,v)\ \text{ and } \ \rho (t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(t,x,v)\,\mathrm dv$$

I am trying to prove the momentum is conserved:
$$q(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^6} v \,f(t,x,v)\,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dv \Rightarrow  q' (t)=0$$

**I need some help to prove that** This is my attempt,
I first substitute the equation of $f$ into the expression:
$$
q'(t) = \int \partial_t [v\,f(t,x,v)]\,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dv
\\
= \int v \left(-v\cdot \nabla_x f (t,x,v) + \nabla_x \phi (t,x) \cdot \nabla_v f (t,x,v)\right) \,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dv
$$
Secondly, I noticed that the first term is equal to zero after an integration by parts (passing the $x$-derivative to $|v|ˆ2$ which does not depende on $x$), therefore
$$
q'(t)= \int v\,\nabla_x\phi(t,x)\cdot\nabla_v f(t,x,v)\,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dv
$$
**What can I do next to show that $q' =0$?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about considering $\Big(v \nabla_x\phi(t,x)\Big) \nabla_v f(t,x,v)$ and integrating by parts twice (first for $v$ and then for $x$)?

Comment: then I will get firstly $-\int \nabla_x \phi\ f $ and then $\int \phi \nabla_x  f$, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to follow from there, sorry.

Comment: Integration by parts on $v$ is a good start, but you want the distribution function isolated without any derivatives on it - as to be able to related it to $\rho$ - so integration by $x$ is not a good idea. That leaves you with $\int_x \rho \nabla\phi$ after doing the $v$ integral and then you know that $\rho = \nabla^2\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your expression, integrating by parts and then using your definitions of $\rho$ and $\phi$
$$
q'(t)= \iint_{\mathbb R^6} v\,\nabla_x\phi(t,x)\cdot\nabla_v f(t,x,v)\,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dv = - \iint_{\mathbb R^6} f(t,x,v)\,\nabla_x\phi(t,x)\,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dv
\\
= - \int_{\mathbb R^3} \rho(t,x)\,\nabla_x\phi(t,x)\,\mathrm dx = - 4\pi\gamma\int_{\mathbb R^3} \rho(t,x)\,\nabla_x (K*\rho)(t,x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
where $K$ is the fundamental solution of the Poisson equation ($K(x) = \tfrac{c}{|x|}$). This can be written
$$
q'(t) = 4\pi\gamma \iint_{\mathbb R^6} \rho(t,x)\,\rho(t,y)\,\nabla K(x-y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y
$$
Since $\nabla K(x-y)$ is an odd function, $q'(t) = 0$.